# How to detect changes of material table data source that have been mutated by functional methods

Tags: angular, angular-material

why mutating material table data source by functional methods like splice etc... doesn't trigger any changes to the render!, unlike assignment operator which leads to directly rendering new mutated data.

I've tried to user change detector after the `splice` but that didn't work

```
 updateDataTable(deletedItemId) {
    this.dataSource.data.splice(...);// this is what I mean by mutating data by functional methods 
      }
```

Comment: based on your reputation, you've been on Stack long enough to know to show code.

Comment: @Sandra and you don't seem to have enough reputation to know that you should be courteous :) as for the OP, data sources are abstracted, don't mutate the `data` property, but instead create a new datasource.

Comment: hi .. i've somethimrd this issues .. i don't remembe if with mat table ... try to matTableDataSource.data = [] and then riassgn data

Comment: @trichetriche https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask && https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I'm pretty sure these are the community standards, and for good reason.

Comment: Never said otherwise. I'm saying you're rude and should not be.

Comment: as @trichetriche said, data sources are abstracted and I can create a new one, please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not mutate your data source.

Angular material provides an abstraction layer to avoid you doing that.

If you want to edit your data, simply create a new data source with the edited data.

```js
const data = Array.fill(10);

this.dataSource = new MatTableDatasource(data);

const updated = data.map(() => 'some text');

// DO NOT
// this.dataSource.data = updated;

// DO
this.dataSource = new MatTableDatasource(updated);
```